# JPA fetching too many entries

Tags: jpa, join, fetch, one-to-many

I have a Customer Entity with a OneToMany relationship to an Invoice Entity.

In plain old sql i can do "select customer_name,customer_age,[some other fields] from customer, invoice where ... [put some filtering here]", which gets me exactly one record with the fields i need.

In JPA i use "select c from Customer c join c.invoiceCollection where ... [same filtering as above]"

This works, but i get the Customer entity with *all* its associated invoices.
This is nonsense, because i pull a huge amount of (invoices) data from the database, which i do not need. I need only my customer data with exactly one invoice, as specified in the where clause.

To make things worse, i have to loop over the Customer.invoiceCollection in order to find the one specific invoice needed. This costs me even more time plus it exposes my "where" clause to the middle-tier.

Question: is there a JPA select syntax which fetches exactly one record from a one-to-many relationship, as defined in the where clause?

Things tried so far:
a) lazy loading. This does not work, throws an exception whenever i try to access Customer.invoiceCollection.
Even if it worked, i'd get a Collection with some 1000 entries, which i do not need.

b) changed my jpa statement to "select c,i from Customer c join c.invoiceCollection i where ...". This returns me an array of objects, which i have to manually map to a Customer / Invoice entity.
It works, but it makes the ORM philosophy obsolete. If i perform all the mapping from relational database records/fields to java objects manually in my code, why do i need JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most infuriating things about JPA. For example, you NEED the OneToMany side if you want Customer to cascade delete Invoices. In most cases you'd like to tell Invoices to delete itself when a Customer is deleted so that Customer does not necessarily need to know about Invoice.

My suggestion for you is that you keep the OneToMany there but get the Lazy Loading working. In your code, do not access "Customer#getInvoices" directly (unless you really need all of them).

This will allow you to do queries on customers that join to invoices without loading them.

I'm guess the exception you are getting just has to do with transaction boundaries which can be easily fixed.

For a lot of these relationships I often add the OneToMany as a private instance variable but I don't create the #getter method. That way I can use it in queries, setup cascade delete, etc. but I don't provide a way to accidentally load thousands of invoices from a customer.

Oh, and for those queries where you need exactly one invoice with its associated customer you should just do the JPA query on the Invoice and then call #getCustomer on that invoice object. That will be eagerly fetched for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This sounds to me the most usefull suggestion so far. At the moment i try to fix the transaction boundaries as you suggested (not easy :-( )

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly one invoice with the related customer, why don't you create a query simply based on Invoice?

```
select i from Invoice i where [same filtering..]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time - both of you. 

Unfortunately 2/3 of our busines cases require the one-to-many relationship as it is now. E.g. in the majority of cases we need the customer with (all or a subset) of its invoices. 

As an additional difficulty, the entity Customer has several one-to-many relationships (invoices, addresses, books ...).
So i have to do  a select from invoice, afterwards a select from address, afterwards a select from books - every time for the same customer.

But at any case i will give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use one-to-many relationship in this case.

One-to-many relationships are suitable for situations when objects at "many" side are logical parts of object at "one" side (e.g. relationship from `Invoice` to `InvoiceLine`).

In you case you need a unidirectional many-to-one relationship from `Invoice` to `Customer`, so that you can query it as follows:

```
select i from Invoice i where ...
```

Then you can use `customer` field of `Invoice` to access `Customer` or filter by its properties.